# MySQL - "Group" multiple rows by day, then sort by most viewed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by, sql-order-by

What I am looking to do is sort videos on a tube front page. All the videos would be grouped together in a section by day. Multiple days on each page. Within each day section, I would then like to order the videos by most viewed or any other type of second sorting algorithm.

Desired result:

```
Todays Videos:
  - Video 1 (100 views)
  - Video 2 (90 views)
  - Video 3 (50 views)

Yesterdays Videos:
  - Video 4 (400 views)
  - Video 5 (250 views)
  - Video 6 (100 views)

Feb 15th Videos:
  - Video 7 (600 views)
  - Video 8 (500 views)
  - Video 9 (300 views)
```

Then there would be pagination, so the second page would continue with Feb 14th, 13th, etc...

FYI, I know it's probably not the best way, but the database structure uses a unix timestamp stored in an int(11) field.

I am using CodeIgniter, but just any normal MySQL example would be great, I would like to do this with a single query. I am unsure if I can do this with groupby / orderby or some other functions. I was reading on grouping sets but not sure if I am on the right track.

Any help would be great because I am completely stuck on this one.

Edit (Adding Table Structure):

```
video_pk int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
views int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
scheduled_date int(11) NOT NULL
```

scheduled_date is unix timestamp

Comment: If you are able to supply any database schema that you have at present i.e. table designs then that would be helpful

Comment: Have you designed/created the db tables yet?

Comment: You should be able to do it with group by and order by statements, something like GROUP BY 'date' ORDER BY  views DESC

Comment: I added the 3 columns needed for this in the question above, there are other columns for title, description, duration, etc. Thank you!

Comment: Would changing the scheduled_date field to be either a DATE or DATETIME be viable?  If it were a DATE (if that's all the granularity required) then it would simplify matters

Comment: I am open to anything that improves the site / code / DB. Preferably I would like to keep it with the current field type since it is a live website with a good amount of traffic that uses this timestamp in a lot of places.

Comment: @Chris,  Wouldnt it be easier to do an "ORDER BY scheduled_date, views"...  (With a limit for your pagenation)....  Then all you have to do is output / structure the date in your front-end

Answer (score 0):

Like Simon mentioned in the comments above, it'd be much simpler if the scheduled_date field was just a Date, for what you're using.  If this was the case, then you can get the result with the following query:

```
SELECT 'scheduled_date', 'video_pk', 'views' FROM 'table' 
GROUP BY 'scheduled_date',video_pk ORDER BY 'scheduled_date','views' DESC
```

With it as a timestamp, things get more complicated as you have to have some way to determine whether the videos are in the same day, thus making it harder to do it with a single query as you'd like.

Edit: You mentioned that you'd like to keep it as a timestamp to use with other portions of the site.  Perhaps a possible solution would be to keep an additonal field that stores the timestamp alongside the date, or if you don't need the specific time, and just the date it important, you can convert the date to a timestamp when you need it.

Comment: I am not sure if it makes a difference, but the timestamp is per day, not per hour / minute. So yesterdays videos for example all have the same timestamp.

Comment: if the timestamp is the same for all videos of that day, then you can group it with time stamp.

Comment: hmmm, I will have to try this again. I must have done something obviously incorrect because it was grouping all videos for that one day into a single video row when I tried this.

Comment: really? hm... if this is the case, I might be using the wrong query, i'll double check it and get back to you on that

Comment: I updated the query, I'm not able to test it myself first, but this should give you multiple rows, categorized by the date, and in the order by views.